# How to translate with Angular locl interpolations in html

Tags: angular, internationalization

I have this code in my html:

```
<span i18n="@@itemHeaderNewName">
    {{item.get('itemId')?.value ? "*" : "New item"}}
</span>
```

Is it possible to translate "*" and "New item" with angular i18n using locl? How can I make it? Since in my translation file I have just:

```
@@itemHeaderNewName: "{$INTERPOLATION}"
```